# Regex to find text after period

Tags: regex

Do you know what the regex expression would be to find the last text after a period.

exampels

```
 this.is.a.test = test
 GOOG.N.QQ.HH = HH
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your string `this.is.a.test` or `this.is.a.test = test`?

Comment: What language or regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 11):

Short and simple: a list of characters at the end of a line, not containing the full stop:

```
[^.]+$
```

Since GREP is greedy by default, it will match as much as possible characters, so for these two test strings it will return everything after the last full stop until the end-of-string.

Answer (score 1):

This will match text following the last dot, or the whole string if there are no dots:

```
(?<=\.|^)[^.]+$
```

The *whole* match is your target, because a (non-capturing) look behind is used to assert the match is preceded by a dot or start-of-input.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/fJNZwmXMf0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go with something like:
`\.([^\.]+)$`

Hope it helps!

Comment: No need to escape the dot in the character class. Most characters (including the dot) lose their special meaning when in a character class.

Comment: This expression includes the full stop in its match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last word of the quadruple

```
(?<=\.)(\w+)(?=\s*=)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oP5vA9/)